# New Android studio project errors in mainactivity (Android Studio 1.3)

Tags: java, android

I have done Android projects in the past with Eclipse. Now when I try to start using the Android Studio IDE when I create a new project the brand new untouched mainactivity.java file has import errors. I have looked on multiple forms and can not find out how to fix the problem. I have tried to go to file>Invalidate Cache> Invalidate and restart

I have tried every method I could find and think of and it is still not working.

This has been a 3 day project just to get the new project setup to work I don't understand why this is not working or how to fix it.

Here is the mainactivity.java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; //this is one of the errors
//it says that AppCompactActivity cannot be resolved
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

this is my build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.compeny.project"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
}
```

in build.gradle

You might be missing the library. Maven/IntelliJ projects can be imported like above, in Android Studio gradle

Comment: if i do that i get a error saying that the support library should not be lower then the target sdk

Comment: its pretty obvious that you need to either pull down app's target sdk in gradle or pull up the library's

Comment: ok i understand how to pull down the target sdk but i am not sure how to pull up or down the library's

i am new to android studio and currently it is proving to be a big pain

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you need some more help. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: yah can you help me pull down the library please?

Comment: i am sorry but i would like some more help because it is still not working. i am getting tired of waiting around for answers this is insane and really should not be this hard. so could someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: to pull down a library, you can go to its source code (if you have directly imported it). If its a gradle library/ aar file you just have to pull up the project to use the library. BTW most devices are above sdk 17 so it shouldnt be an issue.